# How to only affect element being changed, and not others

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have a page where it will list all the users for admin management.
I may be dumb or tired but I can't seem to get my head around this part.

Each table row is going to contain a select element with a list of classrooms, so that when changed it automatically updates the database with the selected option value for that user.

```
<select id="setClassroom">
    ...
</select>
```

So every row is going to contain this same element. How can I get jQuery to only use the element that is being used on that row, and not any other row.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert($('option:selected').text());
});
```

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scoping:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert($('option:selected',this).text());
});
```

The addition of `this` in the selector scopes to only the current `select`

Comment: I knew it was an easy thing, I just don't get why I didn't know how. Thank you, this worked a charm.

Comment: @PeterKA Will do when it allows me to in 7 mins.

Comment: @A.Wolff - that will return the value, the OP asked about the text - not the same thing.

Comment: @Jamiec That would make sense but i read: `updates the database with the selected option value` now i'm not sure OP knows difference between both. Anyway `value` should be used, that's not the purpose of innerHTML to carry some data but that's a different debate for sure :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, you're absolutely right. Quite likely OP has something like `<option>one</option>` where `this.value` and option text would be the same, but we may never know :)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Also, your `<select>`s should not all have the same id.